# is there a way to pass an array of integer values to interior.colorindex

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am taking a report chopping out what I don't need. It splits by the area. Then I am trying to reformat it. During the reformatting instead of having the words "Full", "Empty", and "WAIT". I need the rack location backgrounds to be colored. Green for Full, light-red for empty, and another color for wait. I am dealing with a large amount of data.

When I set the range I can pass all the value from the array to the range

```
Set RngRow = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(LastRow, MatCount + 1))

RngRow.Value = MyMaterial
```

But I am getting a type mismatch when I try to pass the array of integer values for the cell background colors

```
  RngRow.Interior.ColorIndex = MyFormat
```

I am missing something here and I think its a case of not seeing the forest for the trees. I would appreciate any pointers to what I doing wrong

```
SupplyArea  Plnt        Material                   Number         Kanban Quantity       BUn
 ID number  No. Status        Actual quantity   Date    Time        MRP elemnt      Replen.elemt    

CVC015I10B  1170        2958910             2       10      EA
112827  1   WAIT        10  5/26/2015   7:39:19     JITCll      1345847 
112828  2   WAIT        10  5/26/2015   7:39:38     JITCll      1345848 

CVC015I10B  1170        3698163             2       8       EA
112829  1   WAIT        8   5/26/2015   7:40:37     JITCll      775674  
112830  2   WAIT            00/00/0000  0:00:00
```

My code is this

```
Sub PK18_EPID()
  Dim SourceSheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
  Dim HeadingLoop, RngCount, LastRow, RowCount, MatCount As Long
  Dim DelCntr, ShtCnt As Integer
  Dim MyMaterial()  As String
  Dim MyFormat() As Integer
  Dim HeaderValues, SheetNames, SheetUsedRows As Variant
  Dim RngRow As Excel.Range

  Set SourceSheet = Sheets("pk18")
  With SourceSheet
    .Select
    For DelCntr = 1 To 4 Step 1
       Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    For DelCntr = 1 To 8 Step 1
      Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next
  End With
  SheetNames = Array("SS", "NN", "LL", "CV", "Non_Std")
  SheetUsedRows = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
  HeaderValues = Array("Material", "Supply Area", "Kanban ID", "Status")
  RngCount = UBound(HeaderValues) + 1
  For HeadingLoop = 0 To UBound(SheetNames)
    Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = SheetNames(HeadingLoop)
    Set TargetSheet = Worksheets(SheetNames(HeadingLoop))
    Set RngRow = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 1),     TargetSheet.Cells(1, RngCount))
    RngRow.Value = HeaderValues
  Next HeadingLoop

  With SourceSheet
    Do While .UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1
      MatCount = 0
      Do
        MatCount = MatCount + 1
      Loop While SourceSheet.Cells(MatCount + 1, 1).Value <> ""

      ReDim MyMaterial(MatCount)
      ReDim MyFormat(MatCount)
      MyMaterial(0) = SourceSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value
      MyMaterial(1) = SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
      MyFormat(0) = 1
      MyFormat(1) = 1
      RowCount = 0
      For RowCount = 2 To (MatCount)
        MyMaterial(RowCount) = SourceSheet.Cells(RowCount, 1).Value
        Select Case True
          Case SourceSheet.Cells(RowCount, 3).Value = "FULL"
            MyFormat(RowCount) = 35
          Case SourceSheet.Cells(RowCount, 3).Value = "EMPTY"
            MyFormat(RowCount) = 2
          Case SourceSheet.Cells(RowCount, 3).Value = "WAIT"
            MyFormat(RowCount) = 15
        End Select
      Next
      Select Case True
        Case Left(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, 2) = "SS"
          Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("SS")
          SheetUsedRows(0) = SheetUsedRows(0) + 1
          LastRow = SheetUsedRows(0)
        Case Left(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, 2) = "NN"
          Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("NN")
          SheetUsedRows(1) = SheetUsedRows(1) + 1
          LastRow = SheetUsedRows(1)
        Case Left(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, 2) = "LL"
          Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("LL")
          SheetUsedRows(2) = SheetUsedRows(2) + 1
          LastRow = SheetUsedRows(2)
        Case Left(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, 2) = "CV"
          Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("CV")
          SheetUsedRows(3) = SheetUsedRows(3) + 1
          LastRow = SheetUsedRows(3)
        Case Else
          Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("Non_Std")
          SheetUsedRows(4) = SheetUsedRows(4) + 1
          LastRow = SheetUsedRows(4)
      End Select
      Set RngRow = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1),    TargetSheet.Cells(LastRow, MatCount + 1))
      RngRow.Value = MyMaterial
      RngRow.Interior.ColorIndex = MyFormat
      For DelCntr = 1 To MatCount + 1
        SourceSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
      Next
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't assign colorindex like that - has to be a single value per call.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are going to contain predefined text values ("FULL, "EMPTY", or "WAIT"), just apply [conditional formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html) to this column and let Excel do the coloring for you.